Resolving gitlab conflicts locally
I created a branch conf_mr_1 and tried to create a Merge request which resulted in a conflict. This was intended just for some learning purpose. When I try and create a merge request gitlab gives me an option to resolve conflict locally. So I on my existing branch conf_mr_1 tried to execute the first 2 command as mentioned in step1 . While git fetch origin ran without issue, second one failed with error fatal: a branch named 'conf_mr_1' already exists which again is expected as branch conf_mr_1 already exist. Gitlab would not be definitely wrong :) so I am wondering what am I doing wrong  here ?

